# auto.arima with xreg: Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

Tags: r, matrix, forecasting, arima

I am trying to fit a dynamic auto.arima model with xreg regression variables.
When I try to run the code, I get the following error:
Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

Here is the code that results in the error:

```
library(forecast)

v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v3 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v4 <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

dynamicmatrix <- data.matrix(cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4))
dynamicmatrix

ts <- ts(dynamicmatrix[,1], start=c(2036,2))
dynamicmatrix <- data.matrix(dynamicmatrix[,-1])
fit <- auto.arima(ts, xreg=dynamicmatrix[])
```

Does someone know what might be the problem that causes this error and how I could fix it?

Thank you,
Niels

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would help the community help you if you made your question reproducible; please include your data as an object  (presumably a matrix) dynamicmatrix < - matrix(...) where ... is the data. If the data set is large provide a sample which still causes the problem you want resolved in the question. Check out [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your comment Peter. I have now included the data for the matrix in my question.